# How do I iterate over all words up to permutations of the alphabet in Python?

Tags: python, iteration, permutation, python-itertools, alphabet

This doesn't seem like such a niche problem to me, but I surprisingly can't find anything about it online. Suppose you have an alphabet set (for me the first m letters of the usual alphabet) and you want to efficiently iterate over all words of the alphabet (in order to do some analysis on them for example). This is easy to do in Python; just do something like

```
import itertools
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[0:m]
for l in range(0, 200):
    for word in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=l):
        #foo
```

However for my particular problem, when I do analysis on a string, it is easy to predict how the answer will change when I apply a permutation of the alphabet to the string. Speed is critical in my program so there is no point iterating over *all* words; if I could iterate over words *up to permutations of the alphabet* then I could decrease the search space and thus speed by a factor of len(alphabet) factorial (in my case it would also mean I have less data in memory). I had a look and there doesn't seem to be a command in itertools for iterating in this manner

It would be easy to cobble together some code which, at the start of each new word length, stores all the words of that length in a list, thins the list out with respect to permutations of the alphabet, and then makes this list into an iterable to be iterated over. The issue would be that as the length of the words gets big, this list would not fit in memory. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of where this type of iteration would start and end?

Comment: I'm not sure what "up to permutations of the alphabet" means in this context. How does this hypothetical command differ from the existing `itertools.permutations`? Can you give an example of what values you would expect the command to generate?

Comment: @Kevin so for example if I took the alphabet to be the first three letters of the ordinary alphabet, I wouldn't want to iterate over both 'accabc' and 'bccbac' since the latter is obtained from the former via the permutation a |-> b, b |-> a, c |-> c of the alphabet. itertools.permutations seems totally inappropriate; if I were to do something with itertools.permutations(alphabet), this would be iterating over words whose lengths are the same as the length of the alphabet, but I want to iterate over all words of the alphabet.

Comment: @Tomothy32 well I would want to start the iteration at the empty word, and I would only iterate over the one letter word 'a' since all other one letter words are related to it via a permutation. For two letter words I would just need to iterate over 'aa' and 'ab', for three it would be 'aaa', 'aab', 'aba', and 'baa' (I think, and also it doesn't have to be exactly these strings; there just shouldn't be two words which are related by a permutation of the alphabet). My program never ends; it just processes longer and longer strings, but I suppose I could only run it up to a certain...

Comment: ...length, in which case it's difficult to say which word would be the final word in the iteration since there's not really a natural order on words up to permutations of the alphabet. I suppose you could use the lexicographic order (like in the dictionary, i.e. '... < aa' < 'ab' < 'ac' < 'ba' < 'bb' < 'bc' < ...), but it seems like it would be difficult to say which is the lexicographically greatest word of a given length up to permutations of the alphabet.

Comment: Ok, I think I get your meaning. I think a memory-efficient solution is possible. I'm going to play around with this.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, I appreciate it. Hopefully there's an efficient way to only iterate over the desired words, but if there isn't then I imagine it's possible to put an if statement where '#foo' is in the question which will check whether the word is one we want or not. If you do find a way to iterate only over the words we want, keep in mind that it would only be useful if it runs faster than implementing such an if statement into itertools.product.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible to do this with a small amount of memory. I estimate that the memory necessary is proportional to the length of the string being generated.

Basically we only want strings that can't be Caesar-Ciphered into a string that's lexicographically smaller. I don't have a formal proof, but I suspect these strings always satisfy a particular property: The first occurrence of a character in the string never appears after a character that's lexicographically larger. For example, `"abbacb"` satisfies this property because the first `a` appears before the first `b`, and the first `b` appears before the first `c`. With this property it should be possible to recursively generate all such strings starting with the smallest one.

```
def gen_words(alphabet, size=None):
    if size is None:
        i = 0
        while True:
            yield from gen_words(alphabet, i)
            i += 1
    if size == 0:
        yield ""
    else:
        for s in gen_words(alphabet, size-1):
            #determine which characters are permissible.
            used_characters = sorted(set(s))
            #any character that has already been used is permissible.
            for c in used_characters:
                yield s + c
            #the lexicographically smallest unusued character is also permissible.
            if len(used_characters) < len(alphabet):
                yield s + alphabet[len(used_characters)]

g = gen_words("ab")
for i in range(20):
    print(next(g))

#or, to generate an infinite number os trings, use:
#for s in gen_words("ab"):
#    print(s)
```

Result:

```
a
aa
ab
aaa
aab
aba
abb
aaaa
aaab
aaba
aabb
abaa
abab
abba
abbb
aaaaa
aaaab
aaaba
aaabb
```

Comment: Your property and your code don't quite match - for example, with an alphabet of `'abc'`, the word `'ac'` satisfies your property, but your code (correctly) does not produce it.

Comment: You could avoid the `used_characters` recomputation by passing an additional argument representing how many of the alphabet's characters have been used. (This is enough to determine which characters have been used.)

Comment: (Correct property: no character appears in a word until all characters "lower" in the alphabet have appeared in that word. This can be proven correct by induction on the word length.)